# Returning a variable from a class with python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I'm trying to get a variable from a class but for some reason its not coming through. its probably really simple but I really cant think of anything

Here is the code its not done yet I've only made a login screen:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
correct = False
#-------------Functions-----------------------------------------------------

class LoginMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_2 = Label(self, text="Welcome to the rota system")
        self.label_3 = Label(self, text="Please enter the password to continue:")
        self.label_1 = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)

        self.label_1.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        self.label_3.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=3, sticky=W)


        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command = self.login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def login_btn_clicked(self):

        password = self.entry_1.get()

        if password == "1234":
            correct = True

        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect password")
        return correct



#-----------------Main-Program----------------------------------------------

window = Tk()
LoginMenu(window)
if correct == True:
    print("Yay")
    LoginMenu.self.destroy()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `correct` variable is never declared when the password is incorrect, so it can not be `return`. Even if it is declared it will only exist in the scope of the class method. It is not a global variable and you should not use one inside a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable within the class only has a local scope.

A good way would be to define the variable `correct` as a class member:

```
class LoginMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.correct = False
```

and then set it in your function:

```
def login_btn_clicked(self):

        password = self.entry_1.get()

        if password == "1234":
            self.correct = True
```

Your could access it from the global scope via (no need for `== True`, btw)

```
loginmenu = LoginMenu(window)
if loginmenu.correct:
```

The problem is though that this won't work in your case. You enter your main loop after your `if` construct. Please have a look at the Tkinter docs how to properly structure a Tkinter app.

Answer (score 1):

To reference a global variable inside a local scope you have to define that variable inside the class like this:

```
global correct
```

(inside the function login_btn_clicked)

Comment: Although this is technically correct, global variables are not very pythonic :)